# Centraliser of an element in $\mathbf{S_n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I Recently came across a formulae which gives number of elements in a centraliser of an elements in Symmetric group of  n symnbols in $\mathbf{S_n}$

According to that formulae the number of elements in the centraliser of of an element with $a_i$ cyles of length $l_i$ where $\sum_i a_il_i=n$ in $\mathbf{S_n}$ is

$$\prod_i(l_i)^{a_i}{a_i}!$$

Now consider $\mathbf{Z_{10}}$ and an element $(12367)$ then the centraiser of this element will be
$(5)^1(1!)(1)^5(5!)=5.5!$

I want to varify wether this formula is right.

Comment: «Formulae» is a (slightly outdated form of) the *plural* of the noun «formula», so that «that formulae» does not work. it is quite ok, in any case, to use the nice and simple «formulas».

Comment: What is wrong with this <<formula>>, I mean formulae

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The centralizer of an element $\sigma$ is the stablizer of $\sigma$ under the action of $S_n$ on itself by conjugation. Now the orbit stabilizer theorem says that if ${\rm Stab}(\sigma)$ is the stabilizer and $\mathcal O(\sigma)$ its orbit, $$|{\rm Stab}(\sigma)||\mathcal O(\sigma)|=n!$$

It remains to recall that the orbit of a cycle of type $(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n)$ -- that is, there are $\sigma_i$ cycles of length $i$ -- has size $$\frac{n!}{\prod i^{\sigma_i}\sigma_i!}$$

This gives that the stabilizer has size $\prod i^{\sigma_i}\sigma_i!$.

Comment: So this formulae be used for every element.